# Adding new slots to Survey with React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to add new slots when creating a Survey with React. Every new slot is a component called NewQuestion and the original state is an Array of just one component. There is an event handler that pushes to this array one more component NewQuestion, but this doesn't render at all. I guess it could be the reference to the array.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import NewQuestion from "./question";

const NewSurvey = () => {
    let arrayOfQuestions = [<NewQuestion />];
    const [currentQuestions, setCurrentQuestions] = useState(arrayOfQuestions);

    const addQuestion = () => {
        arrayOfQuestions.push(<NewQuestion />);
        console.log(arrayOfQuestions);
        setCurrentQuestions(arrayOfQuestions);
    };

    return (
        <div className="container general">
            <div className="container vertical central">
                <h1>New Survey</h1>
                <p>
                    I am baby biodiesel cronut tumeric, wolf unicorn pop-up
                    sriracha williamsburg truffaut vaporware stumptown you
                    probably have not heard of them skateboard chartreuse
                    flexitarian.
                </p>
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Insert the title of your Survey"
                    ></input>
                    {currentQuestions.map((item) => item)}
                    <h4 onClick={addQuestion}>add question here</h4>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewSurvey;
```

In the end, I would like to have just a list of components to render. Any hint what's messing here the code?

EDIT: Already found the solution using the spread operator when setting the new State

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the array `currentQuestions` in the state to preserve question data, not UI components. In general it should only contain the minimal amount of information needed to represent your UI.
You can pass it to  component via props if needed. Have a look at the example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import NewQuestion from "./question";

const NewSurvey = () => {
    const [currentQuestions, setCurrentQuestions] = useState([]);
    const addQuestion = () => setCurrentQuestions(['new question', ...currentQuestions]);
    

    return (
        <div className="container general">
            <div className="container vertical central">
                <h1>New Survey</h1>
                <p>
                    I am baby biodiesel cronut tumeric, wolf unicorn pop-up
                    sriracha williamsburg truffaut vaporware stumptown you
                    probably have not heard of them skateboard chartreuse
                    flexitarian.
                </p>
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Insert the title of your Survey"
                    ></input>
                    {currentQuestions.map((item) => <NewQuestion question={item} />)}
                    <h4 onClick={addQuestion}>add question here</h4>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewSurvey;
```